# How do I can protect a html page from accessing by way of address bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

We have a form page and when I click the submit button, after checking fields and validity of the fields, we should see a "Welcome Message" on another html page.

Now my question is: How do I protect this html page from being accessed by way of browser address bar? I do not want this page to be seen by typing in address bar.

For example, if the user fills the form correctly and than he sees the "Welcome Message" on another html page and by looking at the address bar, as a result he can access in the page by typing the address in address bar!

Comment: You need to store the logged-in status in for example a session or database and start at the top of the other page whether that status is set.

Comment: when you post your form, if it validates, store something in your php session and only show the second page if that variable is set, otherwise do a header redirect back to the original url (you can also clear the session var once that second page is hit if you only want them to view it once).  I would also put a noindex on it so search engines don't show it in search results

Answer (score 0):

You could check server side that the user came from a POST

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // print good page
}
else
{
    // Print bad page or redirect
}
```

Comment: I suggest using session. Checking for post only is not enough (imo)